# Suppose that V and W are isomorphic vector spaces over an infinite field F. Prove that there are infinitely many isomorphisms between V and W.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So here is how I started...

V, W isomorphic over F , then $\exists \space T:V \rightarrow W$ such that T is invertible.

Let

$R: V \rightarrow W$

$S_{\alpha}: W \rightarrow W$

$R:S_{\alpha}: \rightarrow W, \alpha \in F$

$S_\alpha$ is invertible for any $\alpha \neq 0$

For $x \in w$

$ S_{\alpha}(x) = \alpha x$

$S_{\alpha}^{-1}(x) = \alpha^{-1}x$

This is where I get stuck. I want to show that $S_{\alpha}^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse of $S_{\alpha}(x)$

I was thinking something along these lines.

$\alpha x * \alpha^{-1} x$

$\alpha \alpha^{-1} x^2 $

$x^2$

But that doesn't seem right

Comment: Hint (even though there are already good answers): each vector space has infinitely many bases (even if the dimensions are $1$).

Comment: ...unless the spaces are the trivial space $\;\{0\}\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show the map $S_\alpha^{-1}$ is the inverse of $S_\alpha$, not that their images are inverses. That is, you want to show $S_\alpha^{-1}(S_\alpha(x)) = S_\alpha^{-1}(\alpha x) = \alpha^{-1}(\alpha x)=x$ is the identity map.

So indeed, $S_\alpha \circ T$ gives you a different isomorphism $V \to W$ for each $\alpha \in F \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ is an isomorphism, given a non-zero scalar $\alpha\in F$ we can consider the linear transformation $f_\alpha$ defined by $f_\alpha(v)=\alpha f(v)$. Prove it is also an isomorphism.